# Building Dynamic Template URL in AngularJS config

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET MVC site. Wherein there are different tenant users.

so if a user wants to view his tenant page he has his own unique slug name.

eg: www.xxxxx.com/(slugname)

Now in AngularJS can I dynamically add this slugname to the  **templateUrl like templateUrl: 'Home/(slugname)/Test'**  in the config using $scope or ng-init or anything?.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean `$location`, something like:

```
 $location.path('/' + path).search(search);
```

See docs [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24location)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for Angular Dynamic Routing. Please refer http://gregorypratt.github.io/AngularDynamicRouting/ for details.

Also refer this similar question on SO: [AngularJS dynamic routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681116/angularjs-dynamic-routing).