# Parameter is null in controller when using $routeProvider in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

Routing

```
 .when('/student/:Id', {
           templateUrl: 'student/index',
           controller: 'studentEditCtrl'
       })
```

my link contains

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" ng-href="#/student/@v.Id">Edit</a>
```

my Angular controller

```
angular.module('newApp')
  .controller('studentEditCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope, $stateParams) {
      $scope.isTabActive = true;

      $scope.Id = $stateParams.Id;
      alert("studentEditCtrl");
  }]);
```

I have also used $routeParams instead $stateParams.

My MVC Controller

```
  public ActionResult Index(int? Id)
        {
            Student st = new Student();
            if (Id != null)
                st = sRepository.Students.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == Id);
            return View(st);
        }
```

In Asp.net MVC Controller Id is always Null,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks #Starscream1984
I got my answer from
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681116/angularjs-dynamic-routing).

```
 .when('/student/index/:Id', {
             controller: 'studentEditCtrl',
             templateUrl: function (urlattr) {
                 return '/student/index/' + urlattr.Id;
             },

        })
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change your link to:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" ng-href="#/student/{{Id}}">Edit</a>
```

Presuming it sits within the scope of `studentEditCtrl`.

And use `$routeParams`

Comment: <a class="btn btn-primary" ng-href="#/student/2">Edit</a>

what if i put 2. it's also not working. ng controller alert is firing after Mvc Controller has returned view.

Comment: This is confusing me a little - it seems more like you are trying to mix MVC and client-side routing, which is not really going to work as you describe. You should have the routing done client-side, and then when you need to get the student record, you should make a Web API controller call via http.

Comment: Is there any way to define dynamic parameter in templateUrl??

Comment: I don't think so - like I said, I think you're approaching this all wrong. Are you trying to build a SPA or an MVC app?