# Angularjs no predefined routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I'm playing with angular trying to create some routes without specifying statically the paths

I have the following ng-routes now:

```
route
.when("path/of/first/file",{templateUrl: "path/of/first/file.html"})
.when("path/of/second/file",{templateUrl: "path/of/second/file.html"})
.when("path/of/third/file",{templateUrl: "path/of/third/file.html"})
```

As you can see in this example there's a fixed rule for each file:

```
path/of/%dynamic_path%/file  -> path/of/%dynamic_path%/file.html
```

So i should have something like a regexp:

```
route.when("path/of/(.*)/file",{templateUrl: "path/of/$1/file.html"});
```

I want be able to add paths without having to specify them in the router configuration ( suppose I have thousands of files ). Is there something that will allow me to do this in angular ng-route or ui-route?

Comment: You want dynamic routing, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681116/angularjs-dynamic-routing#23807920)

Comment: i've tried that but it seems that the function of templateUrl is processed only at config time. So it's valid for a single route

Comment: It was my fault. I fixed my errors and it works now ! :D thanks

Comment: if you add it as an answer i'll accept it

Comment: Excellent, and nah the answer was already provided ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS dynamic routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681116/angularjs-dynamic-routing)

Answer (score 0):

You want dynamic routing, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681116/angularjs-dynamic-routing#23807920)
                    – RamblinRose