# How to send value of variable from controller to config function?

Tags: angularjs

My code...

### Config function

```
 config.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider'];
function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider ) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            controller: 'LoginController',
            templateUrl: 'pages/login.view.html',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
        .when('/datepicker', {
            controller: 'DatepickerController',
            templateUrl: 'pages/datepicker.view.html',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
         .when('/password', {
            controller: 'PasswordController',
            templateUrl: 'pages/password.view.html',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
         .when('/datatable', {
            controller: 'DatatableController',
            **templateUrl:  "I WANT TO GET HERE"**
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: 'pages/login.view.html' });

}
```

### Controller

```
(function () {

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('DatepickerController', DatepickerController);
DatepickerController.$inject = ['$location',  'UserService', '$rootScope'];
function DatepickerController($location,  UserService, $rootScope) {

frm.submit(function(ev) {
    var eCode=123;
    var start_date = $('#start_date').val();
    var end_date = $('#end_date').val();    
    var start_date = new Date($('#start_date').val());
    var sDate = start_date.getTime();
    var end_date = new Date($('#end_date').val());
    var eDate = end_date.getTime();
    $location.path('/datatable');
    var path="pages/datatable.view.html?ecode="+eCode+"&sDate="+sDate+"&eDate="+eDate;//**I want to send this url to routeprovider**        
    ev.preventDefault();
});

}
})();
```

I cannot access $rootScope in config function...

I need to assign this url(in path variable) to templateUrl which is in routeProvider...

How to send that url to config function?

any idea...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681116/angularjs-dynamic-routing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in you controller create a factory and assign the `url` to that factory method and then in config return the router url in templateUrl function.

TemplateUrl can also be a function that returns a url. It takes one preset parameter, stateParams, which is NOT injected.

```
     .when('/datatable', {
        controller: 'DatatableController',
        templateUrl:  function(Mconfig){
          return Mconfig.getUrl(); //config.getUrl is service method to return the url
        }
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    })
```

sample factory

```
factory('Mconfig', function() {
    return {
        var url;
        getUrl: function() {
            return url;
        },
        setUrl: function(_url) {
            url = _url
        }
    }
})
```

your controller

```
frm.submit(function(ev) {
    var eCode=123;
    var start_date = $('#start_date').val();
    var end_date = $('#end_date').val();    
    var start_date = new Date($('#start_date').val());
    var sDate = start_date.getTime();
    var end_date = new Date($('#end_date').val());
    var eDate = end_date.getTime();
    var path="pages/datatable.view.html?ecode="+eCode+"&sDate="+sDate+"&eDate="+eDate;//**I want to send this url to routeprovider**       

Mconfig.setUrl(path); 


    $location.path('/datatable');


    ev.preventDefault();
});
```